# Unable to get properties in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I am trying to use properties in SpringBoot Appilcation. But when I am trying to call `new MappingProperties().getLogin()` I alway get a null-value. Please, can somebody explain me what I am doing wrong?

**Application class**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@EnableConfigurationProperties
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here goes how I am trying to access properties

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
@PropertySource("classpath:mapping.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "user")
public class MappingProperties {
    private String login;

    public String getLogin(){
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login){
        this.login = login;
    }
}
```

And here goes my `mapping.properties` file which is located in `src\main\resources\mapping.properties`

```
user.login = /login
```

Also here goes my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.9.RELEASE'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.4.RELEASE'
}

configure(allprojects) {
    apply plugin: 'propdeps'
    apply plugin: 'propdeps-maven'
    apply plugin: 'propdeps-idea'
    apply plugin: 'propdeps-eclipse'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.5.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:1.5.4.RELEASE'

    optional "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"

    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.5.4.RELEASE'
}
```

Comment: try adding `@Configuration` to the `MappingProperties.java` object... plus the annotations suggested by @Vitolds

Comment: @georgesvan why would you do that? if it's a configuration file annotate it as such... which `MappingProperties` seems to be

Comment: Neither `@Component` or `@Configuration` did not help

Comment: Ah, you are also missing `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on the `Application` class

Comment: Does not it is included in @SpringBootApplication?

Comment: Try @autowired MappingProperties = mappingproperties;  mappingproperties.getlogin;

Comment: @georgesvan, you are right

Comment: That bean have to be created by the spring container, not by just new MappingProperties()

Comment: autowired solves this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@yurii  You are creating new Object of MappingProprties `new MappingProperties().getLogin()` that will always return null. You have to get object of MappingProperties from spring context. As per your code, spring DI is not aware of your `new` object of MappingProperites.

*(If you want use `new` then every time you have to inject value of `login` field, but i don't think it's a good way to do your work in spring)*
 I'm using your code as reference.

```
//simple and basic config for any spring boot application
@SpringBootApplication 
@EnableAutoConfiguration 
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
 }
}
```

There are no. of ways to work with properties file. We will discuss two of them (you are mixing these concepts with each other). Let's make it very clear to understand.

**First Way:**

► In this way, we have to tell the name of properties file for field value injection to spring

► Create anyname.properties file
    *anyname.properties*

```
user.login:/login
```

► Create new config java file
    PropConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:anyname.properties")
public class PropConfig{

//you can inject property values anywhere in the code that is under spring context(e.g. @Service, @Repository, @Component etc)
@Value("${user.login}")
private String login;

public String getUserLogin(){
    return login;
}
}
```

**Second Way:**

► We will use annotation @ConfigurationProperties

► Create NewProps.java file

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "user")
public class NewProps{
//value of this field will be automatically mapped to "user.login" in "anyName.properties" file
private String login;
 public String getUserLogin(){
    return login;
 }
}
```

► As per [documentation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.java) of *@ConfigurationProperties*:

> Annotation for externalized configuration. Add this to a class
>   definition or a
>       {@code @Bean} method in a {@code @Configuration} class if you want to bind and validate
>       some external Properties (e.g. from a .properties file).

```
//here we are making property values as fields of custom bean
//now property values will be accessed in a way, as field of some ordinary java bean
@Configuration
public class NewConfig {

 @Bean
 NewProps newProps(){
    return new NewProps();
 }
}
```

► access property values

```
@Autowired
NewProps newProps;


//in your code
...
newProps.getUserLogin();
...
```

*Note: Please let me know, if you have any query about it*

Comment: What if i have 2 properties file. Should it pick up properties from both the file. It's not working so for me. Any reasons?

Comment: Did you use @PropertySource(value="classpath:anyname2.properties")

Answer (score 2):

You have to manage the dependencies between your 2 classes by dependency injecting or wiring them in the Spring container.

So, inject **MappingProperties** as an instance variable into the invoking class by Autowiring it **:**

```
@Autowired
private MappingProperties mappingProperties; 

...
mappingProperties.getLogin();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't know about your login field, i mean it doesn't know that something has to be injected there. You should tell spring to inject the value.

Try annotating `private String login;` with `@Value("${login}")`.

Or remove `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "user")` and annotate with `@Value("${user.login}")`

Comment: @Value does not support relaxed binding

Comment: @georgesvan could you elaborate? the answer's syntax seems valid to me

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but none of that did not help.

Comment: Also, in case of  @Value doesn't it have to look like that @Value("${login}")?

Comment: @yurii You are correct. That'd be the correct syntax